# fastest non-jquery way to do sibling function?

Tags: javascript, function, dom

If I have some dom nodes

```
<div id="foo">
    <h1 class='selected'>this is only an example</h1>
    <p>abc</p>
    <p class='selected'>def</p>
    <p>ghi<p>
</div>
```

I can use jquery to change the class from one `p` element to another something like this (given `node` is the dom node I chose somehow) without affecting other siblings of the node that might also have the same class/proprty name:

```
    $(node).addClass("selected").siblings("p").removeClass("selected");
```

What's the best modern non-jquery way to do this?

Comment: Fastest way is to keep a reference to the previous `node`, and remove just its class.

Comment: *"What's the best*" questions lead to opinions, not answers, moreover when the scope is not defined. Anyway, here is one non-jquery way to do it as a one liner if for anyone one-liners are "the best" : https://jsfiddle.net/592vomke/

Comment: Noted, re: question title. Your fiddle reminded me about `:scope`, which I'd forgotten about. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To Remove the class from the existing selected Item and adding the Class to the Next Sibling, use the below code (Pure Javascript).

```
var selectedP = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
selectedP.classList.remove("selected");
var nextSiblingToAddClass = selectedP.nextSibling();
nextSiblingToAddClass.classList.add("selected");
```

use previousSibling or nextSibling to traverse through the Ps, and use classList.remove or classList.add to remove a class or add a class respectively.
Hope that this solves your issue.

But i would recommend the easier way is to use Jquery.

Comment: isn't the `nextSibling` a node that is "further down" (higher in index) than the selected node?  What happens if the new node to select is before that current node? What happens if there were somehow two `p.selected` nodes and I wanted to replace it with just one new `p.selected`. The jquery code handles that. In jQuery, `siblings` is a collection of both all of the matching previous and next nodes, then `removeClass` applies to each of those elements.